# Leaflet Curve (Bézier) using Angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, bezier, curve

I'm using [angular-leaflet-directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/) in my AngularJS application to show Leaflet maps. At this time I'm playing around with paths - drawing lines between two points. This is working great, but at this time it is rendered as a straight line. I want a smooth Bézier curved line. I've found 2 plug-ins on the Leaflet site [Leaflet.Curve](https://github.com/elfalem/Leaflet.curve) and [Leaflet.Canvas-Flowmap-Layer](https://github.com/jwasilgeo/Leaflet.Canvas-Flowmap-Layer), but none have an AngularJS implementation.

Question: has anyone integrated this into the angular-leaflet-directive? if so, can you give some pointers how to do this? I've looked at the code, but I don't know how to start. And of course I've Googled around but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need search "How to add a custom control to angular-leaflet-directive".

You can find a lot of sample [here](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/tree/master/examples)

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("demoapp", ["leaflet-directive"]);
    app.controller('LayersOverlaysMarkerclusterController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            ripoll: {
                lat: 42.20133,
                lng: 2.19110,
                zoom: 8
            },
            layers: {
                baselayers: {
                    osm: {
                        name: 'OpenStreetMap',
                        type: 'xyz',
                        url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                        layerOptions: {
                            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                            continuousWorld: true
                        }
                    },
                    cycle: {
                        name: 'OpenCycleMap',
                        type: 'xyz',
                        url: 'http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                        layerOptions: {
                            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.opencyclemap.org/copyright">OpenCycleMap</a> contributors - &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                            continuousWorld: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                overlays: {
                    hillshade: {
                        name: 'Hillshade Europa',
                        type: 'wms',
                        url: 'http://129.206.228.72/cached/hillshade',
                        visible: true,
                        layerOptions: {
                            layers: 'europe_wms:hs_srtm_europa',
                            format: 'image/png',
                            opacity: 0.25,
                            attribution: 'Hillshade layer by GIScience http://www.osm-wms.de',
                            crs: L.CRS.EPSG900913
                        }
                    },
                    cars: {
                        name: 'Cars',
                        type: 'markercluster',
                        visible: true
                    }
                }
            },
            markers: {
                m1: {
                    lat: 42.20133,
                    lng: 2.19110,
                    layer: 'cars',
                    message: "I'm a moving car"
                },
                m2: {
                    lat: 42.21133,
                    lng: 2.18110,
                    layer: 'cars',
                    message: "I'm a car"
                },
                m3: {
                    lat: 42.19133,
                    lng: 2.18110,
                    layer: 'cars',
                    message: 'A bike!!'
                },
                m4: {
                    lat: 42.3,
                    lng: 2.16110,
                    layer: 'cars'
                },
                m5: {
                    lat: 42.1,
                    lng: 2.16910,
                    layer: 'cars'
                },
                m6: {
                    lat: 42.15,
                    lng: 2.17110,
                    layer: 'cars'
                }
            }
        });
        $scope.move = function() {
            $scope.markers.m1.lng = $scope.markers.m1.lng + 0.1;
        }
    } ]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer sgrillon gave was very useful and gave insight how the extension mechanism of Leaflet works. For future readers who are searching to integrate Leaflet.Bezier.js, these are the things I've done.

1) Add controls tag to your Leaflet map

2) Extends the map and instantiates the custom control - in my example L.Bezier

```js
angular.extend($scope, {
  center: {
    lat: 50.653657,
    lng: 4.383432,
    zoom: 7
  },
  layers: {
    baselayers: {
      xyz: {
        name: 'OpenStreetMap (XYZ)',
        url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        type: 'xyz',
        layerOptions: {
          showOnSelector: false
        }
      }
    },
    overlays: {}
  },
  paths: {},
  markers: {},
  controls: {
    custom: new L.bezier({
      path: [
        []
      ]
    })
  },
  defaultIcon: {},
  defaults: {
    scrollWheelZoom: true,
    minZoom: 7,
    maxZoom: 14
  }
});
```

Where the curved line should be drawn, create an new instance of L.bezier and add it to the custom control.

```js
// create bezier curved path
var bezier = new L.bezier({
  path: [
    [{
        lat: operator.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: operator.geometry.coordinates[0]
      },
      {
        lat: selectedController.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: selectedController.geometry.coordinates[0]
      }
    ]
  ],

  icon: {
    path: "images/icons/car.png"
  }
}, dash_straight);

$scope.controls.custom = bezier;
```

It works!

[image]